# AngularJs UI Modal without $scope and extra ModalController (resolve)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

- I want to implement UI Modal in AngularJS without using $Scope and without implementing the ModalController(resolve).
- I am  not using $scope in my Controller. I am using vm = this. So I dont know what value to assign to scope while openinig the Modal.
- I also dont want to use resolve, as it involves creating one more Controller.

Please find my code below: Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modaltemplate.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>Modal Header</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal Body</p>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.close()" data-dismiss="modal">Close
        </button>
    </div>
</script>
```

**CONTROLLER** Look at scope in $uibModal.open() function.

```
angular
    .module("app", ["ui.bootstrap"])
    .controller("MyController", MyController)

MyController.$inject = ["$uibModal"];

function MyController($uibModal) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.open = open;
    vm.close = close;

    function open() {
        vm.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'modaltemplate.html',
            scope: //what should I assign here, I dont want to use $scope. Or in other words, I want to assign 'vm' here.
        });
    }

    function close() {
        //This function is not getting called as it does not understand the vm.
    }
}
```

**I have tried the following things:**

1. In the HTML, set ng-controller="MyController as vm".
2. Also tried setting various Values for scope, controller, and controllerAs in the $uibModal.open() function.

But nothing seems to working. Can anybody please help me out.

Comment: You've eliminated all the options used to avoid the use of $scope. All alternatives require you to create your own Modal Controller.

Comment: You mean to say that with this Coding Structure, it is mandatory to create the Modal Controller? And there is no way around it. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have problem with ***Close*** function, you can set $dismiss() for close modal instance, also you can pass parameter in $dismiss function for further use, try this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modaltemplate.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>Modal Header</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal Body</p>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$dismiss('cancel')" data-dismiss="modal">Close
        </button>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Hasan. Thats exactly what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new scope in main controller

```
var modalScope = $scope.$new();
```

assign what you need on new scope (or whole vm):

```
modalScope.vm = vm;
```

and then assign it as modal scope:

```
vm.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'modaltemplate.html',
    scope: modalScope
});
```

Just make sure you clear it when closing/destroying modal

```
modalScope.vm = null;
```